# Setting Android Privacy Policy

Tags: android, admob, privacy-policy

I am using AdMob in my android application. Do i need to create a Privacy Policy in my application to inform users about cookies that Google uses?

If yes where do i need to put it?

Do i must write it in descriptions on Google Play? Or on fist run do I must show a fragment window? Or can I write the Privacy Policy just in section "About App"?

What do I write?

I read the Google Documents, but i didn't understand clearly.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2519872?hl=en

Comment: No and do not worry about it.

Comment: @JaredBurrows so what do you think about this part of link up? =

"Why should I have a privacy policy?

You will need to determine what makes the most sense for your app and your users. The privacy policy field is an additional tool that will allow users to better evaluate the apps they wish to download."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**To clarify for anyone who is finding this question:**

The answer is yes, you need a privacy policy for your app if you are using AdMob. Refer to: [AdMob Help](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en) (bottom of the page).

> ... Additionally, your app's privacy policy may need to be updated to reflect the use of personalized advertising (formerly known as interest-based advertising) served via the Google Mobile Ads SDK. Please take a moment to review your app's privacy policies and ensure that they are up-to-date. Because publisher pages and laws vary across countries, we're unable to suggest specific privacy policy language...

They essentially want you to inform users about the use of targeted advertising. **They don't explicitly tell you what to write** though.

Personally I think it should be enough to write something about that you use AdMob to serve ads and that AdMob uses the devices advertising id to serve personalized ads based on the users interests (which includes collecting and analyzing user data). A [link](https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/ads/authenticated) to the Google page to opt-out of personalized advertising and to Googles Privacy Policies ([here](http://www.google.com/policies/privacy/) and [here](http://www.google.com/policies/privacy/partners/)) can't hurt.

[This](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en&visit_id=0-636242563978851577-3297603297&rd=1#privacy) also suggests that you need to have at least a link to your privacy policy in your app and on the store page. But maybe AdMob doesn't count as handling sensitive data, so maybe the link to the policy on the store page is optional in this case.

As a side note: If you use any Google Services (e.g. Location, Firebase, Places Api) you probably need a privacy policy

Comment: Can’t you use admob in a way that doesn’t let it do user tracking?

Answer (score 3):

#### Things changed in 2017 (even without AdMob):

**AdMob is another subject: I talk about any app event without AdMob (*my case for example*)**

Google threatens to remove my open source app [JSAir](https://github.com/MacKentoch/jsair-mobile) just for `http://android.permission.READ _PHONE_STATE` (*for UX: I need to check connection is active or not = that's all*).

**I had the surprise of receiving a mail from Google who wants me to create a privacy policy website now (*I did not have before*).**

*I will have to say something like:*

> This application stores/send/read nothing apart javascript air website information!!! So there is no better privacy conscious application.

Comment: yeah i got an email which warns me about privacy policy. I have to write a privacy policy otherwise they remove my app...

Answer (score 0):

I made a public gist and posted the url [here is the gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/FielddddMMMMarshal/519d7de4b17ca7c16f85c98a3e1df385/raw/626c2160cd3286f7d6c598baf642cce3294ebca3/Noti-fication%2520Policy) 
you can check here 
[play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smallapps.Notification&hl=en)

Comment: please summarize the link here